# fill dynamic input with select html

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I am trying to make a dynamic form which consists of being able to add rows dynamically and the same with a select I take the values ​​of the select and put them in the inputs of the first row, I would like to know how to fill in the other selects because it only works for me with the first row
my select

[image]

```js
function cambioOpciones(e) {
  const combo = document.getElementById('opciones'),
    [FECHA, MONEDA, NUMCTA, FAMILIA, CONCEPTO, FACTURA, DENOMINACION_SOCIAL, VENDEDOR] = document.getElementById('opciones').value.split('_');
  document.getElementById('fecha').value = FECHA;
  document.getElementById('moneda').value = MONEDA;
  document.getElementById('numcta').value = NUMCTA;
  document.getElementById('familia').value = FAMILIA;
  document.getElementById('Concepto').value = CONCEPTO;
  document.getElementById('showId').value = FACTURA;
  document.getElementById('denominacion').value = DENOMINACION_SOCIAL;
  document.getElementById('vendedor').value = VENDEDOR;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  let row_number = 1;
  $("#add_row").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let new_row_number = row_number - 1;
    $('#venta' + row_number).html($('#venta' + new_row_number).html()).find('td:first-child');
    $('#ventas_table').append('<tr id="venta' + (row_number + 1) + '"></tr>');
    row_number++;
  });
  $("#delete_row").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (row_number > 1) {
      $("#venta" + (row_number - 1)).html('');
      row_number--;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <select name="products[]" class="form-control" id="opciones" onchange='cambioOpciones();'>
    @foreach ($ventas1 as $ventas)
    <option value="{{$ventas->FECHA}}_{{$ventas->MONEDA}}_{{$ventas->NUMCTA}}_{{$ventas->FAMILIA}}_{{$ventas->CONCEPTO}}_{{$ventas->FACTURA}}_{{$ventas->DENOMINACION_SOCIAL}}_{{$ventas->VENDEDOR}}">
      {{ $ventas->FACTURA }}---{{$ventas->CONCEPTO }}
    </option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
</td>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please change the templating to pure rendered HTML in a [mcve]

Comment: You need delegation and to use class instead of ID which need to be unique

Comment: Thanks, I still put a picture to understand it

Comment: Could you explain to me what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delegate to be allowed to have one script work on dynamically inserted elements.

Also use classes since IDs need to be unique

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const cambioOpciones = () => {console.log("changed") }
  const $tb = $("#tb");
  $tb.on("click", ".add_row", function(e) {
    $tb.append($tb.find("tr").eq(0).clone(true))
  });
  $tb.on("click", ".delete_row", function(e) {
    const $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    if ($row.prev().length>0) $row.remove()
  });
  $tb.on("change", "[name='products[]']", cambioOpciones)
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="products[]" class="form-control">
          <option value="val">val</option>
          <option value="val">val</option>
          <option value="val">val</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><button type="button" class="add_row">Add</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="delete_row">delete</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```